# installing pyHook without prior download python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, keylogger, pyhook

So, I'm trying to make a simple keylogger and I have this next bit of code:

```
try:
    import pyHook, pythoncom

except:
    os.system("pip install pypiwin32")
    os.system("pip install pyHook")
    import pyHook, pythoncom
```

the installation of pypiwin32 works, and after doing the command

```
os.system("pip install pypiwin32")
```

I can use pythoncom.
however, the second command doesn't seem to work.

I want this to work on every computer, hence - without a need to download a whl file. is it possible to install pyHook like that?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I mean. Your asking people to help you to essentially steal stuff. But sure I'll help. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/keyboard/
Check this out

I don't think your code would 100% work on an pcs.

Comment: "Hack to learn, not learn to hack". this is basically a school project to learn more about sockets. nothing is going to be stolen.

Comment: Ahh then hack away my dear fellow. Hack away. If you haven't already check these tutorials out. https://null-byte.wonderhowto.com/how-to/hack-like-pro-python-scripting-for-aspiring-hacker-part-1-0159118/